# What command do I use to fix this problem?

Tags: java, android, selenium, automation, appium

My main goal is to create a program that can automate an **android** app to do everything you would with your fingers.

[image]

I wrote this line of code so that if that switch is turned **ON**, the code will switch it **OFF**.

`driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/shipping_checkbox")).click();`

But when I run my code again, that switch is now **OFF** by default.

I need a command that leaves the switch alone if it is already **OFF**.

Does anyone know what command to use?

Comment: so, if I get this straight... you want to be able to set the flag to 'off', when it's on, but not back to on again after setting it off?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: seems a bit fishy. what if the user changes his mind? either way, it's always a posibility to set it on disabled when OFF, that way, it'll also be visually clear to the user he can't change the value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether the switch is ON or not. You could achieve this using the following code:

```
if(driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/shipping_checkbox")).isSelected()){
   driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/shipping_checkbox")).click();
}
```

**Updated**:

As mentioned by Muzammil, `isSelected()` is not working as expected. Alternatively, you could use the `checked` attribute:

```
MobileElement shippingCheckbox= driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/shipping_checkbox"));
if(shippingCheckbox.getAttribute("checked").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
   shippingCheckbox.click();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work? Recently I tried to use in my framework but it was not working. Please check also this.  https://developers.perfectomobile.com/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=29558008#content/view/29558008

Comment: In the appium docs, there is no deprecation warning: http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/selected/

Comment: You are right but Its not working solution for Android and IOS. Kindly check    https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6712

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to check slider is **on** or **off**.

This is Node details of Slider.

[image]

Option-1: By using **text**

Here we will click only if slider is On.

```
MobileElement sliderElement=driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/shipping_checkbox"));
    String sliderStatus = sliderElement.getText();
            if (sliderStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("On")) {

              sliderElement.click();    

            }
```

Option-2: By using **Attribute**

Here we will click only if slider is On.

```
MobileElement sliderElement=driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/shipping_checkbox"));
 String sliderStatus=sliderElement.getAttribute("checked");
            if (sliderStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {

              sliderElement.click();    
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I made a mistake in reading this, and missed that it was an Android app, so Javascript is likely unavailable. This comment will only help someone with the same issue on web browser testing, or any situation where Javascript can be executed on the application.

Additional possibility for checking. **Not** that it is superior to other options.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Extensions;

string selector = "com.offerup:id/shipping_checkbox";
if(driver.ExecuteJavascript<bool>($"return document.getElementById('{selector}').checked")) {

    driver.findElement(By.id($"{selector}")).click();

}
```